# Windows 2012 SNMP Memory Usage OID

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, net-snmp

I'm having difficulty tracking down an SNMP OID that will give me some form of memory utilization for Windows 2012 Servers. Has anyone came across one?

For previous windows versions I would use `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1.1.2`, combined with `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1.1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Features Removed or Deprecated in Windows Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831568.aspx) article:

> SNMP is deprecated. Instead, use the Common Information Model ([CIM](http://www.dmtf.org/standards/cim)),
>   which is supported by the WS-Management web services protocol and
>   implemented as Windows Remote Management.

Even though SNMP became deprecated you can install it as a feature from Server Manager:

- [Install SNMP on Windows Server 2012](http://michaeljgirard.com/index.php/install-snmp-on-windows-server-2012/)
- [How to Install SNMP and Configure the Community String](https://support.managed.com/kb/a764/how-to-install-snmp-and-configure-the-community-string.aspx)

As for CIM / WMI you can try with PowerShell:

- [Use PowerShell to Simplify Collecting Performance Information](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/31/use-powershell-to-simplify-collecting-performance-information.aspx)
- [Committed Bytes Rule](http://mpwiki.viacode.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=155486)

```
SNMP                                                 | CIM/WMI
-----------------------------------------------------+--------------------------
1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1.1.2 / memoryCommittedBytes | \Memory\Committed Bytes
```